# Как найти распределение вероятностей для непрерывной количественной переменной в python?

Tags: python, scipy, теория-вероятностей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть список значений непрерывной количественной переменной(от 10 млрд до 80), всего 70 значений. Я хочу получить распределение вероятностей для каждого значения.
P.S Я знаю про distplot у seaborn и параметр density у hist pyplot, но когда я их вызываю для того, чтобы построить график, у меня почему-то по оси y встречаются значения равные 6 или 8, в общем, вероятностью тут и не пахнет.

Comment: ну так и приведите свой код в вопросе.

Comment: И данные и код - всё в текст вопроса добавьте

Comment: Мне просто нужно получить ответ на вопрос("Как найти распределение вероятностей для непрерывной количественной переменной в python"), к чему здесь код? В P.S просто лирическое отсупление.

Comment: Я не очень в статистику, может речь о `pdf`, тогда смотреть здесь https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html

Comment: Ещё вот здесь скрещивают `distplot` с кастомной функцией, чтобы строить `pdf`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56782822/8324991

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо за ссылки на материал, документацию читал, проблема в данных скорее всего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас не должно смущать, что плотность вероятности больше единицы.

К этой функции предьявляются два требования:

- значение функции неотрицательно,
- интеграл от функции по всей оси `x` должет быть равен 1.

Пример: мы знаем, что некоторая случайная величина равномерно распределена на интервале `[-0.1, +0.1]`. Внимание, вопрос: чему равна плотность вероятности? Ответ: на интервале `[-0.1, +0.1]` плотность вероятности равна `5`, на остальной части `x` равна нулю.

Поэтому в вашем случае проинтегрируйте полученную плотность. Готов спорить, что интеграл получится около единицы.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, что хочет ТС, то это построение графика как на рисунке по 70 данным, которые у него имеются.

Наиболее часто используемый метод процедуры восстановления плотности называется оценкой плотности ядра (Kernel Density Estimation, KDE). Наиболее широко используемым ядром является ядро Гаусса (традиционная колокообразная кривая), но используются и другие ядра.

Библиотека Pandas, дает возможность создавать и накладывать графики плотности с помощью plot.kde (), которая доступна как для объектов Series, так и для DataFrame.

Упомянутая уже  displot() из Seaborn одновременно позволяет отобразить гистограмму и KDE для одномерного распределения.

Но обе эти функции в первую очередь предназначена для целей визуализации.

В различных библиотеках доступны множество других, более эффективных реализаций KDE, в том числе в SciPy (scipy.stats.gaussian_kde и scipy.signal.parzen), в Statsmodels (statsmodels.api.nonparametric) -  KDEUnivariate() и KDEMultivariate(), в Scikit-learn sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity().

А про то, что плотность вероятности это не сама вероятность достаточно доходчиво объясняется, например, вот тут:
[https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/плотность-вероятности-не-есть-сама-вероятность-98b1fc8e0ac5](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-98b1fc8e0ac5)

Если же у ТС другая задача -  например, "натянуть" один из стандартных законов распределения (гауссовый, экспоненциальный, логнормальный, Вейбула, Гамма и пр.) на его данные  - то это совсем другая задача и решается другими методами и инструментами. Хотелось бы все-таки от ТС услышать, что ему в действительности нужно.